# Thread program that calculates pi

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads

Writing a program for class that calculates pi. Got all the coding done and program runs - but for certain values it doesn't work. The program is supposed to take in 2 parameters, the 1st one is the number of elements to calculate pi and the second is the number of threads to use. It works flawlessly for many numbers but then for 1, 2, 5 ,6, 7, 8 and some others it doesn't calculate well. It's probably something with the limits in the loops but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//global variables
int N, T;
double *vsum;

//pie function
void* pie_runner(void* arg)
{
    long j = (long)arg;    
    //double *limit_ptr = (double*) arg;
    //double j = *limit_ptr;

    //for(int i = (j-1)*N/T; i < N*(j) /T; i++)
    for(int i = (N/T)*(j-1); i < ((N/T)*(j)); i++)
    {

        if(i % 2 == 0){
            vsum[j] += 4.0/((2*j)*(2*j+1)*(2*j+2)); 
            //printf("vsum %lu = %f\n", j, vsum[j]);
                  }
        else{
            vsum[j] -= 4.0/((2*j)*(2*j+1)*(2*j+2));
            //printf("vsum %lu = %f\n", j, vsum[j]);
                  }


    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Error: Must send it 2 parameters, you sent %d\n", argc-1);
        exit(1);
    }
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    T = atoi(argv[2]); 

    vsum = malloc((T+1) * sizeof(*vsum));
    if(vsum == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation problem\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(N <= T) {
        printf("Error: Number of terms must be greater then number of threads.\n");
        exit(1);    
    }

    for(int p=1; p<=T; p++)        //initialize array to 0
    {
        vsum[p] = 0;
    }

    double pie = 3.0;
    //launch threads
    pthread_t tids[T+1];

    for(long i = 1; i<=T; i++)
    {
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tids[i], &attr, pie_runner, (void*)i);
    }

    //wait for threads...
    for(int k = 1; k<=T; k++)
    {
        pthread_join(tids[k], NULL);
    }

    for(int x=1; x<=T; x++)
    {
        pie += vsum[x];
    }

    printf("pi computed with %d terms in %d threads is %.20f\n", N, T, pie);

    //printf("pi computed with %d terms in %d threads is %20f\n", N, T, pie);

    free(vsum);
}
```

Values not working:

```
./pie1 2 1
pi computed with 2 terms in 1 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
./pie1 3 1
pi computed with 3 terms in 1 threads is 3.16666666666666651864
 ./pie1 3 2
pi computed with 3 terms in 2 threads is 3.13333333333333330373
 ./pie1 4 2
pi computed with 4 terms in 2 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
 ./pie1 4 1
pi computed with 4 terms in 1 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
 ./pie1 4 3
pi computed with 4 terms in 3 threads is 3.14523809523809516620
 ./pie1 10 1
pi computed with 10 terms in 1 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
 ./pie1 10 2
pi computed with 10 terms in 2 threads is 3.13333333333333330373
 ./pie1 10 3
pi computed with 10 terms in 3 threads is 3.14523809523809516620
 ./pie1 10 4
pi computed with 10 terms in 4 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
./pie1 10 5
pi computed with 10 terms in 5 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
./pie1 10 6
pi computed with 10 terms in 6 threads is 3.14088134088134074418
 ./pie1 10 7
pi computed with 10 terms in 7 threads is 3.14207181707181693042
./pie1 10 8
pi computed with 10 terms in 8 threads is 3.14125482360776464574
 ./pie1 10 9
pi computed with 10 terms in 9 threads is 3.14183961892940200045
./pie1 11 2
pi computed with 11 terms in 2 threads is 3.13333333333333330373
 ./pie1 11 4
pi computed with 11 terms in 4 threads is 3.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: If you would like somebody else to debug your code, please at least indicate which input value(s) do not work, what the expected result is, and what the actual output is (and, if it's not obvious, how those are different).

Comment: I did, all the values that are 3.0 are not calculating correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you used an expression like this `N/T` in your code. Here `N` and `T` are integers. C language (and many others) treat integer dividion not the same way as we do it by hand.

For example, 5/3 = 1, not 1.66667. To get 1.66667, you can cast one of the integer to double.